# Is it possible to know the actual covariance matrix, but fail to take-down heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation?

Tags: estimation, panel-data, autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity, covariance-matrix

Is it possible to know the actual covariance matrix and estimate betas using $\Sigma$, but fail to defeat  the problems caused by heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation and have biased or high-variance, non-consistent beta estimator, non-efficient estimation?

Comment: nah $\Sigma$ encodes those things

Comment: if you knew the actual covariance matrix, then you could use Aitken's estimator to transform the response so that you can run a transformed OLS where the  covariance matrix. has non-zero elements only along the diagonal. But these diagonal elements would not be the same so you still  would have heteroscedasticity.  So, you still would need a procedure to eliminate or reduce heteroscedasticity.

Comment: Note that, assuming you know the covariance matrix makes the elimination of hetrosecedasticity straightforward because you can run a weighted regression where the weights are inversely proportional to the diagonal elements of the ( aitken trasnformed ) covariance matrix. This will result in OLS assumptions being met, atleast with respect to the covariance matrix.